# How to remove OnPrimaryClipChangedListener of ClipboardManager in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-clipboardmanager

I use the following code to monitor the change of clipboard, I hope to remove the monitor when I finish the operation.

But `clipboard.removePrimaryClipChangedListener { }` required to pass parameters, how can I do?

**Code**

```
 btnMonitor.setOnClickListener {
         val clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager

         clipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener {
             if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip() && clipboard.primaryClipDescription.hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN) ) {
                 var pasteData: String = ""
                 val item = clipboard.primaryClip.getItemAt(0)
                 pasteData = item.text.toString()

                 toast("Hi - " + pasteData)
             }
         }  

         clipboard.removePrimaryClipChangedListener {  }  //I don't know how to pass paramaters        
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to [remove OnPrimaryClipChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html#removePrimaryClipChangedListener(android.content.ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener)) you need a reference to lambda you "set" before. Try re-organise the code as follows.

```
private val lambda = ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener {

    if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip() && clipboard.primaryClipDescription.hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN) ) {
        var pasteData: String = ""
        val item = clipboard.primaryClip.getItemAt(0)
        pasteData = item.text.toString()

        toast("Hi - " + pasteData)
    }
}
```

Later you can add and remove the lambda with `clipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(lambda)` and `clipboard.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(lambda)`